# Dask quantile over grouped data

Tags: dask, dask-dataframe

Given a Dask dataframe with columns "eco_regions" and "ndvi", is there any way to group the data by the eco_regions and then compute the 90th percentile (0.9 quantile) of the ndvi values for each group using the ‘tdigest’ method?

MRE:

```
data = {
'eco_regions': ['forest', 'desert', 'forest', 'tundra', 'desert', 'tundra'],
'ndvi': [0.8, 0.2, 0.85, 0.4, 0.18, 0.42]
}

ddf = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(data), npartitions=2)

# Group by 'eco_regions' and compute the 0.9 quantile for 'ndvi'
result = ddf.groupby('eco_regions').apply(lambda group: group['ndvi'].quantile(0.9, method='tdigest'), meta=('ndvi', 'f8')).compute()
```

Comment: Hi, not sure what is the problem. method='tdigest' does not exist. Do you want this to be implemented? Otherwise the Dask code looks good.

Comment: According to the documentation it has been implemented https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.quantile.html

Comment: Since you're first grouping the values, your applying quantile on a chunk of DataFrame, and thus on a Pandas Dataframe. Pandas Series quantile function has no method kwarg.

Comment: Right, agree. So is there any way to achieve what I'm looking into?

Comment: Why do you want to use the tdigest method which is made to estimate quantile over a large collection? Your grouped partitions are to big to fit in memory?